# Regex to match word but only if it doesn't start with a non-alphanumerical character

Tags: python, regex, string

I have sentences that I want to identify words in, but not if it starts with an alphanumerical character. It's fine if it ends with one though.

An example of what I've done;

```
words = ["THIS", "THAT"]
sentences = ["I want to identify THIS word.", "And THAT!", "But I do not want to identify !THIS word", "Or [THIS] word"] 

for sentence in sentences:
        for word in words:
                word_re = re.search(r"\b(%s)\b" %word, sentence) 
                if word_re:
                    print("It's a match!")
```

My output of the code above would be a match in each of the sentences. I would like something that only matches in the first two sentences.
Is it possible to do what I want with regex?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regex like

```py
(?<!\S)(?:THIS|THAT)\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GAzeio/1). *Details*:

- `(?<!\S)` - a left-hand whitespace boundary
- `(?:THIS|THAT)` - a non-capturing group matching either `THIS` or `THAT`
- `\b` -  a word boundary.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/b7fiRl):

```py
import re
words = ["THIS", "THAT"]
sentences = ["I want to identify THIS word.", "And THAT!", "But I do not want to identify !THIS word", "Or [THIS] word"] 

pattern = fr"(?<!\S)(?:{'|'.join(words)})\b"
for sentence in sentences:
    word_re = re.search(pattern, sentence) 
    if word_re:
        print(f"'{sentence}' is a match!")

# => 'I want to identify THIS word.' is a match!
#    'And THAT!' is a match!
```

If `THIS` or `THAT` can contain special chars, replace `pattern = fr"(?<!\S)(?:{'|'.join(words)})\b"` with `pattern = fr"(?<!\S)(?:{'|'.join(map(re.escape, words))})\b"`.

Comment: Thank you Wiktor, that was it! If I may ask; I tried implementing the `re.search(fr"(?<!\S){word}\b", sentence)` , version as well but I think the string formatting with the f-flag was unsuccessfull. Why is that?

Comment: I don't know if this is ok to ask as well, but I hope so since it regards the question above. When I tried to compile the pattern regex, it changed from `(?<!\S)(?:THIS|THAT)\b` into `re.compile('(?<!\\S)(?:THIS|THAT)\\b')`. It added two backslashes. How come?

Comment: @OLGJ Nothing is changed, it is correct. If you use `print(your_regex_string_literal)` you will see the exact text used to initialize the regex object.

Comment: That's what I did! That printstatement resulted in `re.compile('(?<!\\S)(?:THIS|THAT)\\b')` when I compiled it, and `(?<!\S)(?:THIS|THAT)\b` when I didn't.

Comment: @OLGJ I said print *your_regex_string_literal*, not the compiled object.